# Supposedly the same entity, but AssertSame fails. Inconsistent data

Tags: hibernate, caching, junit, assert, jta

I have some problems with my DAO implementation. My scenario: I insert one entity in my database, I get this entity twice from my database. I understand difference between AssertSame and AssertEquals. I guess that the same entity should pass in both cases. In my case AssertEquals passes ,but AssertSame fails.

I have been struggling with that for a long time and any help will be greatly appreciated.

My question is: What conditions have to be met in order to be sure that these two entities are the same? What should I change in my code?

I pasted only parts of my classes and config files which I in my opinion are essential.

StudentEntity class is annotated with @Entity.

I'v prepared the following jUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/dao-context.xml", "/hibernate-context.xml", "/core-context.xml" })
public class BidirectionalTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testBidirectionalRelation() {
        try {
            StudentEntity s = new StudentEntity();
            s.setLogin("Login");
            userService.registerUser(s);
            StudentEntity foundStudent1 = (StudentEntity) userService.findUserByLogin("Login");
            StudentEntity foundStudent2 = (StudentEntity) userService.findUserByLogin("Login");
            assertEquals(foundStudent1, foundStudent2);
            assertSame(foundStudent1, foundStudent2); // fail!
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Part of my service implementation:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

private UserDao userDao;

public AbstractUserEntity findUserByLogin(String login) throws ServiceException {
    Long userId = getUserDao().findUserByLogin(login);
    if(userId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return getUserDao().findUser(userId);
}

public Long registerUser(AbstractUserEntity user) throws ServiceException {
    Long duplicateUserId = getUserDao().findUserByLogin(user.getLogin());
    if (duplicateUserId!=null) {
        throw new ServiceException("Użytkownik już istnieje");
    }
    return getUserDao().insertUser(user);
}
}
```

Part of my dao implementation:

```
@Repository
public class HibernateUserDao implements UserDao {

private EntityManagerFactory emf;

public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
    return emf;
}

@PersistenceUnit
public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}

@Override
public Long insertUser(AbstractUserEntity user) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(user);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) em.close();
    }
    return user.getId();
}

@Override
public Long findUserByLogin(String login) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Long result;
    try{
        result = (Long) em.createNamedQuery("findUserByLogin").setParameter("login", login).getSingleResult();          
    } catch(NoResultException nre) {
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Part of my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Part of my core-context.xml

```
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="atomikosTM" />
    </property>
    <property name="userTransaction">
        <ref local="atomikosUTX" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTM" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" />
<bean id="atomikosUTX" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" />
```

edit:

Thx for your answers. Now I know I need a cache. I found a good explanation: "In JPA object identity is not maintained across EntityManagers. Each EntityManager maintains its own persistence context, and its own transactional state of its objects." I changed my persistence.xml, but my test still fails.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>amg.training.spring.model.StudentEntity</class>
    <class>amg.training.spring.model.SubjectEntity</class>
    <class>amg.training.spring.model.TeacherEntity</class>
    <class>amg.training.spring.model.AbstractUserEntity</class>
    <class>amg.training.spring.model.TeacherDegree</class>
    <class>amg.training.spring.dao.AbstractEntity</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to make it work. I think that lack of cache was not a problem. It is necessary to bind a resource (in our case EntityManagerFactory ) to the same thread. [link to doc of .bindResource() method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#bindResource%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
@PersistenceUnit
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(emf, new EntityManagerHolder(em));
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(emf);
EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(em);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the same object you would have to use the hibernate Query cache. Any queries which go to the database will create distinct objects.

See the following on enabling the query cache : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache

Comment: Thanks, that's something new for me. I tried to configure cache in persistence.xml file, but my test still fails.

Comment: Did you remember .setCacheable(true) on your query ?

Comment: I use hibernate query without .setCallable(). I set `em.setProperty(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true); em.setProperty(QueryHints.HINT_FLUSH_MODE, FlushMode.ALWAYS); em.setProperty(QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_MODE, CacheMode.NORMAL);`, but still no improvements

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `assertSame` is that it compares objects, and not their values, as per the documentation:

**assertSame(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual) - *Asserts that two objects refer to the same object.***

Each retrieval of a student creates a new `StudentEntity` object, although they refer to the same database entry. Try caching your result.

Comment: Thx. Now I understand that first findUserByLogin() hits my database. The second one hits cache so the identity would be the same. I tried to implement this, but my test still fails (edited my post).